# Microsoft DI: If two different classes take the same type in their constructor params, how can I inject different values for them from configuration?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, .net-5

Using Microsoft's generic host DI and configuration, let's say I want two different objects (maybe of different, even unrelated types) that each take a `SomeKindOfParameter` in their constructors. They may need different `SomeKindOfParameter` values to be injected into them, with the values specified in configuration (like, say, in `appsettings.json`). How do I do this?

I know how I can get different values for different `SomeKindOfParameter` instances out of configuration:

```
SomeKindOfParameter parameterForTypeX = config.GetSection("ParamForX").Get<SomeKindOfParameter>();
SomeKindOfParameter parameterForTypeY = config.GetSection("ParamForY").Get<SomeKindOfParameter>();
```

And given a *single* `SomeKindOfParameter`, I know how I can get it injected into both of them:

```
SomeKindOfParameter param = ...
services.AddSingleton<SomeKindOfParameter>(param);
services.AddTransient<IX, X>();
services.AddTransient<IY, Y>();
```

But how can I inject `parameterForTypeX` into `X` and `parameterForTypeY` into `Y`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways:

**Use generic type**

You could define a generic helper type derived from `SomeKindOfParameter`:

```
class SomeKindOfParameter { }

class SomeKindOfParameter<TCategory> : SomeKindOfParameter
{ }
```

Then inject `SomeKindOfParameter` of `TCategory` accordingly to each service:

```
services.AddTransient<SomeKindOfParameter<X>>();
services.AddTransient<IX, X>();

services.AddTransient<SomeKindOfParameter<Y>>();
services.AddTransient<IY, Y>();

class X : IX
{
    public X(SomeKindOfParameter<X> parameters)
    {
    }
}

class Y : IY
{
    public Y(SomeKindOfParameter<Y> parameters)
    {
    }
}
```

**Use [`ActivatorUtilities`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.activatorutilities?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) class**

`ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance` method allows you to pass parameters directly to the constructor:

```
services.AddTransient<IX>(serviceProvider =>
{
    var config = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
    SomeKindOfParameter parameterForTypeX = config.GetSection("ParamForX")
        .Get<SomeKindOfParameter>();

    return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<X>(
        serviceProvider,
        // Parameters not passed through this array will be activated
        // from DI container
        new object[]
        {
            parameterForTypeX
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

he "right" way is to use named options, as described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0#named-options-support-using-iconfigurenamedoptions).

```cs
services.Configure<SomeKindOfParameter>("ParamForX",
                                       Configuration.GetSection("SectionForX"));
services.AddTransient<ServiceX>();

public class ServiceX{
    public ServiceX(IOptionsSnapshot<SomeKindOfParameter> snapshot){
        .... = snapshot.Get("ParamForX");
    }
}
```

While a service collection will only have one service object for each type, you could add a layer of indirection via an "open generic" service, to hide the implementation details and provide a different configuration instance to each service;

```cs
public class Parameter<T> where T : class {
    public Parameter(IOptionsSnapshot<SomeKindOfParameter> snapshot){
        Value = snapshot.Get(typeof(T).Name);
    }
    public SomeKindOfParameter Value { get; private set; }
}

public ServiceX(Parameter<ServiceX> p){
    .... = p.Value;
}

services.AddSingleton(typeof(Parameter<>));
```

There's probably also a way to bind each configuration section on the fly. Based on how `.Configure` is [implemented](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6527f540e4b50bc84eb72705f80d3f2bdd57473b/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions/src/OptionsConfigurationServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L62).

Comment: Thanks! Generally speaking, though, I'd prefer to keep the particulars of the DI framework (like "IOptionsSnapshot") and the configuration mechanics (like "ParamForX") out of the classes themselves. For example, I'm hoping for something like (making up this syntax): `services.AddTransient<IX, X, SomeKindOfParam>("someParam", "ParamForX")`, meaning "When you're asked to resolve an `IX`, use type `X`, and for its constructor's `SomeKindOfParam` parameter named `someParam`, use the `SomeKindOfParam` that has been registered as `ParamForX`. Can that be done? Thanks again.